# Extrude a PNG image spherically

Tags: extrude, 2d

This is my first question in the forum. As a newbie, I would like to ask if a PNG image can be extruded spherically. I need to do this as I have a 2D rock that I want to convert into 3D. Thus the png image will appear the same but it must then become possible to rotate it. Of course once extruded, I can mirror it to form complete sphere. Not much detail is required as the rock will be at somewhat a distance in the game.
The image is attached here:
[image: I wish I could resize it]

Comment: I'm a little confused exactly what you mean by 'extrude spherically'. Also, what is the image shown supposed to be an example result or a texture you're using? Assuming it's a result image that you want to emulate, you can UV map a rock texture to a sphere and deform it to generate your asteroid. If this is what you're asking about I can edit this question to include a step by step guide.

Comment: do you need to dig the holes for real?

Comment: That rock is not spherical. You can project an image onto the side of a true sphere, but getting that shape in blender specifically might be very tricky. However, generating some thing that looks like that from scratch is probably easier than what you’re doing. A wave texture here, some Booleans with randomized spheres there; it shouldn’t be too hard at all.

Comment: @moonboots holes are not necessary, just the visual appearance is needed. @ MrGorbunov The image is a what it needs to appear like finally, but in 3D. If you can make a step by step guide, I would be obliged

Comment: @Asad, so just skip the sculpt detail step, just sculpt the general shape, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier, unwrap and paint it with the Draw brush in Mapping > Stencil mode

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, It was a really r=detailed answer.  I have updated the question and am trying your technique .

Comment: you could also follow the contour with edges, extrude, bevel the edges, unwrap from view and project the image, which would be simpler, but probably won't look as good

Comment: I've edited my answer to propose a simpler solution: you could also follow the contour with edges, extrude, bevel the edges, unwrap from view and project the image

Comment: Just Awesome! This method is indeed simpler for me to work with and closer to what I had in mind. Though being complete beginner, I have to search where to find each of the options.

Comment: I was searching on google and could see this video. What would your comments be for the method in the video here: 
https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=blender+extrude+along+path&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8
starting at 7:32 onwards.

Comment: @Asad please use the "@" so that I'm aware of your message. I'm not sure what you mean about the video, it doesn't seem to have something to do with your initial question, or does it? Maybe ask a new question with the new thing you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm adding a simpler solution as you say that you don't need holes.

**First solution:**

Follow the shape with some extrusions:

[image]

Extrude and bevel:

[image]

Fix the topology, symmetrize (on Y here):

[image]

Unwrap with the *Project from View (Bounds)* mode:

[image]

Give your rock a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and the following material. If you think that the texture is too stretched you can paint the sides with the *Draw brush > Stencil* tool for example, or the *Clone* brush. Lower down the *Specular* value, use a *Bump* node to give a bit of 3D details:

[image]

**Second solution:**

Create a cube, subdivide and smooth it:

[image]

Sculpt it a bit so that it has roughly the same shape as your stone:

[image]

Continue to sculpt, use *Dyntopo* for more precision:

[image]

Symmetrize to have the same shape on both the 2 sides of the object:

[image]

Once you're good, use the *Remesh > Quad* in order to simplify your mesh:

[image]

Unwrap your mesh (*Smart UV Project* mode):

[image]

Give it this node setup with a black image loaded in the *Image Texture* node:

[image]

Paint on the surface, use the *Stencil* option with the stone image as stencil:

[image]

Continue to paint all around the stone:

[image]